# Specific image extension selector in CSS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several images in my project with several extensions (jpg, png, gif).

Is there any way to select these images according to their extensions in css or JQuery.

```
<img src="img/img.jpg"/>
<img src="img/img1.png"/>
<img src="img/img2.gif"/>
```

for example I want images that has .png extension to have `height: 200px;` attribute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the *attribute ends with* selector, `$=`:

```
$('img[src$=".png"]').height(200);
```

The *ends with* selector will inaccurately miss `<img src="test.png?id=1">`.

You could also use the *attribute contains* selector, `*=`:

```
$('img[src*=".png"]').height(200);
```

The *contains* selector will inaccurately select `<img src="test.png.gif" />`.

If file path is all you have to go by, you'll unavoidably have to accept one of these exceptions (unless you want to implement some more advanced filter that strips values after `?` or `#`).

Comment: If you're using a vendor service that appends a question mark on the end followed by arbitrary text (`?1499077424`) for whatever reason, it won't work. Rails does this. I think that's the only reason the filename wouldn't end with the extension. Works with the *attribute contains* (`*=`) selector, though which is just as well because periods aren't allowed in filenames except for the extension.

Comment: `img[src*=".png?"], img[src*=".png#"], img[src$=".png"]` may cover most cases without false positives.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use CSS3 [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
img[src$='.png'] {
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Browser support**

```
Chrome    Firefox               IE     Opera     Safari
All       1.0 (1.7 or earlier)  7      9         3
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all of them, you need to use `.filter()`:

```
var images = $('img').filter(function() {
    return /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/.test(this.src);
}).height(200);
```

Comment: Or multiple selectors, `$('img[src$=".png"],img[src$=".jpg"],img[src$=".gif"]')`

Comment: @DavidHedlund True, but... yuk! (no offense)